# Google Map not loading in ipv6 only network iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, location, ipv6

Apple rejected the app because of Google Map not loading in IPv6 only network. Please check following image.

I didn't find any option in google console to enable IPV6 support.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have face same issue but **google map is working in ipv6 network**.

So you must have to check your application with `ipv6` network.You can check it by simple steps [from here](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/).

Happy to help you..

If you still stuck you can ask me anything. Love 2 Code :)